# Find a diagonal matrix congruent to the following given matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, quadratic-forms

> Given the matrix 
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}1 && 2 && 3 \\ 2 && 0 && 1 \\ 3 && 1 && -1\end{bmatrix}$$
>   Find a Diagonal Matrix congruent to it.

---

I know that the Matrix congruency relation over $n\times n$ symmetric matrices over the real field has the canonical forms as diagonal matrices containing diagonal elements as $1,-1,0$ up to ordering.

My first attempt was to find the explicit orthogonal transformation that can convert the given matrix to a diagonal matrix but that proved to be cumbersome manually (the characteristic polynomial wasn't simple to solve).

Then I figured that $\text{tr}(A)=0$ and $\det(A)=15$. Since determinant is positive (and non-zero) either 1 or 3 eigenvalues are positive. However, $\text{tr}(A)=0 \implies$ some eigenvalues are negative definitely. Therefore, the signature of the form is $( + - -)$. Hence, one congruent diagonal matrix is simply the following:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && -1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && -1\end{bmatrix}$$

Is this reasoning correct? Moreover, is there a simple way to find an explicit transformation leading to a diagonal matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By completing squares you can see that the form is
$$
(x+2y+3z)^2 - (2y+z)^2 -(3z)^2
$$
from which you can work out the change of basis needed.

Comment: Is there a way to geometrically conjure up this completion or is it just a intelligent guess? More specifically, is there intuitive way to come up with this other than a trial method?

Comment: It's called Lagrange's Completion of Squares Algorithm. You look for a variable with non-zero $a_{ii}x_{i}^{2}$, and get rid of all the $x_i x_j$ terms [look at my expression], then the next and so on. If you stick because there are no non-zero $a_{ii}$ there must be a nonzero $2a_{ij}x_i x_j$; you replace $x_i, x_j$  by $y_i+y_j$ and $y_i-y_j$ and all the other $x_k$ by $y_k$ and then you're back  on track.